# Question about deviance in PROC GENMOD

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

Using the PROC GENMOD of SAS, in "Criteria For Assessing Goodness Of Fit", I got :

```
Deviance = 0.6841

Scaled Deviance = 1.1002
```

I know that a model with too large a deviance doesn’t fit the data well, but I dont know which deviance should I take

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest you to tell us what you did in SAS, which procedure you used and which part of the manual to this particular procedure you need help with.

Comment: I used the PROC GENMOD